# How to calculate turn rate from a GPS log?

Tags: qgis, r, gps

I'd like to calculate a rate of turn from a GPS log (GPX file).

Each trackpoint in a GPX track has location and time, and in addition to speed (a common calculation and sometimes embedded in a tracklog) I'd like to calculate the rate at which the aircraft or vehicle is turning, for each trackpoint. That said, I suspect the 'rate of turn' is more accurately reflected by a moving average over several points, and would be interested to see if anyone has examined that.

Sample GPX file [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3451554/tracksample.gpx).

[image]

Open-source solutions in R or QGIS preferred!

Comment: I think you should be more precise about what do you mean with 'turn rate' and what do you expect to find. degree/km? What is the (guessed) 'turn rate' from your figure? 180°/5km? Is it to calculate from the starting point to the last point or between each point i.e the difference between two segments?

Comment: As stated: "... for each trackpoint." i.e. each point should have an associated rate of turn. Turn rate should be in degrees per minute. In the example, the 180° turn happens over 59 seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set up a function for calculating the course (angle between points):

```
angle <- function(pt1, pt2) {
  conv = 180 / pi # conversion radians / degrees
  diff <- pt2 - pt1
  left <- sign(diff[1]) # is X diff < 0?
  left[left == 0] <- -1 # sign(0) = 0, need to keep as nonzero
  angle <- left * (diff[2] * pi + atan(diff[1] / diff[2]))
  angle[angle < 0] <- angle[angle < 0] + 2 * pi
  return(angle * conv)
}
```

Load the GPX:

```
require(rgdal)
setwd(".") # set to the directory where the sample GPX is located.
gpx.trackpoints <- readOGR(dsn = "tracksample.gpx", layer = "track_points", stringsAsFactors = F)
```

We're interested in rates by time, so convert GPX time to POSIXlt:

```
gpx.trackpoints$time <- strptime(gpx.trackpoints$time, "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "GMT")
```

Extract the coordinates as a matrix:

```
gpx.tp <- coordinates(gpx.trackpoints)
```

Loop through the GPX points and add distance, time interval and speed for each point, using the *previous* point as reference.

```
require(raster) # interestingly, this has pointDistance for vectors
for (tp in 2:nrow(gpx.tp)) {
  gpx.trackpoints$dist[tp] <- pointDistance(gpx.tp[tp,], gpx.tp[tp-1,], lonlat=T)
  gpx.trackpoints$interval[tp] <- as.numeric((gpx.trackpoints$time[tp] - gpx.trackpoints$time[tp-1]))
  gpx.trackpoints$speed[tp] <-  gpx.trackpoints$dist[tp] / gpx.trackpoints$interval[tp] # m/s 
}
```

Loop through and add course - the difference between the  of the *current* point and the *following* one:

```
for (tp in 1:(nrow(gpx.tp)-1)) {
  gpx.trackpoints$course[tp] <- angle(gpx.tp[tp + 1,], gpx.tp[tp,])
}
```

Loop through again and look at turn angle and calc rate. Turn angle is the difference between the current point's course and the following point's course:

```
for (tp in 2:nrow(gpx.tp)) {
  gpx.trackpoints$turn[tp] <- gpx.trackpoints$course[tp] - gpx.trackpoints$course[tp -1]
  gpx.trackpoints$turn_rate[tp] <- gpx.trackpoints$turn[tp] / gpx.trackpoints$interval[tp]
}
```

Let's have a look ... adding the points to QGIS, but styling with a rotation dependent on the "course" field:

[image]

[image]

Changing the size of the marker depending on the turn rate:

[image]