# Yaw rate calculation from heading

Tags: gps, heading

I have a GPS log where speed, heading are obtained every 100ms. I would like to calculate yaw rate with this. Can I get the method, algorithm or formula to calculate the same?

I understand using Discretized Second Order Low-Pass Filter with Differentiator formula must be used but unsure of the formula.

Comment: [Solution using R](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/208926/how-to-calculate-turn-rate-from-a-gps-log). I asked about using moving average / filtering at the time but didn't get any answers.

Comment: But you seem to have solved it with R. Have you tested the results against any yawrate sensor reference system?

Comment: What kind of system do you mean? No, haven’t tested it against other sensors. Does the R solution work?

Comment: I have not tried R. I was talking about special sensors which output yawrate directly instead of calculating from heading